# button with low z-index is not clickable

Tags: css

I try to put image and button next to each other when the image covers slightly above the button.

But then the button becomes not clickable.

```
.button{z-index:-1!important;}
.image{z-index:1!important;}
```

Any advice?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: please provide some html code or your actual scenario demo so we can help

Answer (score 0):

Don't completely cover up the button.

- Give it a positive z-index so it isn't under the body
- Give the image a larger z-index
- Don't completely cover the button with an image

Comment: the button is not completely covered.

Comment: the image a little bit cove it at the left and that what i need.
the image as the css:margin-left:-20px;

Comment: @user4858836 — See the first bullet point. The button is completely covered by the `<body>`